# Looking for a dichotomous key to identify primates

Tags: literature, species-identification

I'm looking for a dichotomous key to identify primates by physical and possibly geographical traits.  Any format is fine (print, web, mobile app, etc.).

Other than classroom activities and genetic classification references the best I have found is on WikiBooks: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Dichotomous_Key/Primates